# Перевод сигнала с микрофона в текст

Tags: c++

В Google Translate можно продиктовать в микрофон слова и они преобразятся в текст. Как это сделано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделано на основе [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) с использованием [Speech Input API Specification](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html).

А собственно распознавание речи осуществляется обычно системами на основе скрытых моделей Маркова или нейронных сетей (например, типа RNN, LSTM).